# How can I use the Workflow component to do a parallel approval?

Tags: workflow, symfony

I've been trying to get my head around the new Workflow component in Symfony and looked at the example on [Github](https://github.com/lyrixx/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow). In this example there is a journalist approval and a spellcheck approval and both of these are needed to move to the published place. How can this handle a rejection from either a journalist or a spellchecker? For example, if there was a journalist_reject transition and a spellcheker_reject transition, how could the system end in a rejected state with only one rejection?

Comment: I think what you want is conditional routing as it is in Petri Net, the basis for the Worklow component. Aproval would be a yes/no selection, and the flow from the "no" branch of both aprovals would go to a rejection place. The problem is, I don't know either how to do it in the Workflow component. See: [The Application of Petri Nets
to Workflow Management](http://martinfowler.workflowpatterns.com/documentation/documents/vanderaalst98application.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The symfony workflow component doesn't really work that way without intertwining it with some custom logic. Building that purely with the workflows component would require two transitions in an arbitrary order to transistion from state A (say, a draft) to state B (approved). You could do this with two approvals, of course, by implementing two intermediate states:

- draft -> approved by spellchecker -> fully approved
- draft -> approved by journalist -> fully approved

where in any state before fully approved a transition to rejected is possible. However, the complexity of such a system would increase exponentially with every intermediate transition. A three-approver system would already require a lot more:

- draft -> approved by A -> approved by A and B -> approved
- draft -> approved by A -> approved by A and C -> approved
- draft -> approved by B -> approved by A and B -> approved
- draft -> approved by B -> approved by B and C -> approved
- draft -> approved by C -> approved by A and C -> approved
- draft -> approved by C -> approved by B and C -> approved

so now we've gone from 2 possible flows to 6 possible flows. Addition of a fourth approver would increase the number of possible flows even more, and furthermore would require significant modification of the existing flow.

A better way, in my view, would be to have only the transition from draft to approved and from draft to rejected, but to *only* allow the transition from draft to approved when all required approvers have approved the article, for instance by making the approval action a command instead of immediately triggering the transition, and triggering the transition in your command handler if all approvers have given their approval (easily doable with the existing validation component, for instance). The transition to rejected would not be validated, and would be immediately executed, because any rejection is enough to reject an article. Or maybe not - it would be easy to add requirements for that as well in this setup.

That way, you can add as many parallel approvals as you like without it increasing the complexity of your application one bit, and more importantly, you can add approvers without having to modify your workflow at all.